# iOS Core Image CIOverlayBlendMode behavior

Tags: ios, core-image

I'm having a little trouble understanding the behavior of CIOverlayBlendMode on iOS. If I overlay a solid 50% grey image on my source image, the resulting image is substantially darker than the source. I had expected that overlaying 50% grey would result in no change to the output image (this is the behavior of the overlay blend mode in Photoshop). The documentation I've been able to find doesn't go into any real detail about how this is supposed to work, and as far as I can tell there aren't any parameters to adjust this.

What's the correct neutral tone to get no change in the CIOverlayBlendMode filter? Is there some other detail or nuance I'm missing here?

Answer (score 0):

You may have your `inputImage` and `inputBackgroundImage` parameter values swapped.

For me it worked as expected when the inputImage was the gradient (50% gray in your case) that I wanted to overlay on top of the inputBackgroundImage:

`let image = CIImage(contentsOfURL: url)!
let radialGradient = CIFilter(name: "CIRadialGradient", 
               withInputParameters: [ ... ])!
let overlay = CIFilter(name: "CIOverlayBlendMode", withInputParameters: [
    kCIInputBackgroundImageKey: image,
    kCIInputImageKey: radialGradient.outputImage!,
    ])`